# sending json with similar keys converts to sub array in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

for using an api , I created json file with this data in js:

```
{
   "name[0]": "foo",
   "name[1]": "bar"
}
```

but after I posted it with jquery `$.post` function to my php file , its converted like this:
output with `print_r();`

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
         (
             [0] => foo
             [1] => bar
         )
)
```

but i need them to be key, not an array:

```
Array
(
    [name[0]] => foo
    [name[1]] => bar
)
```

how can I prevent that from converting to array?

Answer (score 0):

`{"[name[0]]":"foo","[name[1]]":"bar"}` is the correct syntax. Errors in your example:

- using single quotes (') instead of double quotes (")
- trailing comma (,) after the "bar"

You can generate this yourself at https://de.functions-online.com/json_encode.html using the following input:

```
array(
"[name[0]]" => "foo",
"[name[1]]" => "bar"
)
```

You can verify the result at https://de.functions-online.com/json_decode.html

Comment: the comma after "bar" was just a type mistake. I did the suggestions but didn't worked!
after doing what you said there was no key value pair in php!

I generate them with this way:

if(item.get(key) != '')  collectedItem["["+key+"[" + i + "]]"] = value;

Comment: Maybe it's time to post your full code since the error is clearly somewehre else.